# ionos mail server unable to send data to hotmail accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, smtp, mail-server, ionos

I have my domain-name hosted on Ionos. Along with the domain-name , I also purchased mail server from ionos.

I have migrated my nameservers from ionos to aws.
I have also added a record for my mail-servers to point to existing records on ionos. (MX record)

It all seems to work but whenever my mail servers have to send data to hotmail account this message is received at my mail-server and hotmail email account is unable to receive required data.

```html
This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.
A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of
its recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es)
failed:
abc@hotmail.com:
SMTP error from remote server for MAIL FROM command, host: hotmail-com.olc.protection.outlook.com (some-ip) reason: 550 5.7.1 Service unavailable, Client host [my-ip] blocked using S
pamhaus. To request removal from this list see https://www.spamhaus.or
g/query/ip/my-ip (AS3130). [BN8NAM12FT047.eop-nam12.prod.prote
ction.outlook.com]
--- The header of the original message is following. ---
Received: from [127.0.0.1] ([aws-ip]) by mail server name
  (mreue109 [some-ip]) with ESMTPSA (Nemesis) id
  some-id-value for <abc@hotmail.com>; Date
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
From: mail server
To: abc@hotmail.com
Subject: Welcome 
Message-ID: <xyz>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Date: --------
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Provags-ID: some junk values
X-Spam-Flag: YES
X-UI-Out-Filterresults: some junk values
```

I have tried to contact both Ionos and AWS Team regarding this issue , so far I have not received any help .
I am looking for guidance on how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hotmail.com is notorious for "eating" mails. I am also using Ionos and I am usually not able to send mails to hotmail addresses.

For some unknown reason hotmail has blacklisted ionos as spammer and nobody seems to know how to fix it.

I hoped that they managed to fix it over the last years, but reading your post that seems not to be the case. At least you got an answer. I have sent mails to hotmail and neither I nor the receiver got any information that the mail failed.

Comment: I talked to ionos support team and they usually take a week to get back to you.
for now , it seems to be fixed ( they managed to make it work ) but error may arise again , you never know with ionos.

Comment: This is rather a problem at the hotmail side than Ionos. Hotmail  has a very strange behaving junk mail filter which is completely   intransparent both to sender and receiver. There is a reason why many websites refuse to accept hotmail adresses for registration.